# Get Video Play Time android from videoplayer

Tags: android

I write this function to get video time . This functions works fine but when I backpress then it throws exception .

```
public void videoTimer ()
        {
            try
            {
                running = true;
                final int duration = mVideoView.getDuration();

                thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            tvVideoTimer.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    int time = (duration - mVideoView.getCurrentPosition()) / 1000;
                                    tvVideoTimer.setText(getTimeString(mVideoView.getCurrentPosition()));
                                }
                            });
                            try
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (!running) break;
                        }

                        while (mVideoView.getCurrentPosition() <= duration);
                    }

                });

                thread.start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException : at com.tact.upmcm.activity.VideoTrainingActivity

Comment: Please post complete text